# Auth fails when token is passed as variable but passes when hard coded

Tags: node.js, authentication, github

I've got a node.js application that checks for a pull request in GitHub.

One of my scripts is called genToken.js and it generates an installation access token. The other, prCheck.js, uses genToken.js and assignes the return value to a variable which is then used in function retrievePR. This is the function:

```
var installationAccessToken = getToken.getInstallationAccessToken(function(res) {});

retrievePR: function(owner, repoName, state, callback) {
var github = new GitHubApi({
  // optional
  timeout: 5000,
  host: 'api.github.com', // should be api.github.com for GitHub
  protocol: 'https',
  headers: {
    "Accept" : "application/vnd.github.machine-man-preview+json",
    "Authorization" : `Bearer ` + installationAccessToken
  }
});

github.pullRequests.getAll({
  owner: owner,
  repo: repoName,
  state: state
}, function(error, data){
  callback(error, data);
});

}
```

This returns the following error:

```
ERROR: Unable to retrive pull requests from github: {"message":"Bad credentials","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3"}
```

If I change the line:

```
"Authorization" : `Bearer ` + installationAccessToken
```

for:

```
 "Authorization" : `Bearer 1234`
```

where `1234` is a manually generated token the authentication does not fail.

Also, if I add `console.log("installationAccessToken", installationAccessToken);` just after `var installationAccessToken = getToken.getInstallationAccessToken(function(res) {});` I see that it outputs `installationAccessToken undefined` and this seems to happen before the token is returned from genToken.js. I assume this is some sort of synchronization issue. I'm not sure how I should deal with it though.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried debugging and checking whether `installationAccessToken` contains token  before generating  `GitHubApi` instance ?

Comment: Apologies @kgangadhar. I just added some extra info.

Comment: Yes, I think `getToken.getInstallationAccessToken` is an asynchronous method, you need to call and wait till you get the token before proceeding further. using promise or async await

Comment: I'm new to node.js so its quite likely I'm wrong but I used a callback. I thought that would have done what you just suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
retrievePR: function (owner, repoName, state, callback) {
    getToken.getInstallationAccessToken((res) => {
        var installationAccessToken = res //here check and assign token from res
        var github = new GitHubApi({
            // optional
            timeout: 5000,
            host: 'api.github.com', // should be api.github.com for GitHub
            protocol: 'https',
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/vnd.github.machine-man-preview+json",
                "Authorization": `Bearer ` + installationAccessToken
            }
        });

        github.pullRequests.getAll({
            owner: owner,
            repo: repoName,
            state: state
        }, function (error, data) {
            callback(error, data);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Let me know whether its working or if you are facing any issue.

Comment: That worked. Seems so simple but I'd have been looking at it all night before I'd have thought of trying that.

I made a minor change by removing `var installationAccessToken = res //here check and assign token from res` and changing the Authorization to `"Authorization": 'Bearer ' + res`

Comment: I added above line, because i was not sure about what `res` is returning

Comment: That was perfect. Thanks for all the help.